# Find out Who am I?

Tags: riddle

> It's not a baby though you hold in the arms close to your bosom.
>
> It's not an Indian man though it has long beard.
>
> It's not a monkey though its tail is bent.
>
> It's not a bird though it has beautiful voice.

```
What am I?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you talking about

> A beard guitar?

It's not a baby though you hold in the arms close to your bosom.

> You hold it close to your bosom while playing it.

It's not an Indian man though it has long beard.

> Does the name of the instrument answers this clue?

It's not a monkey though its tail is bent.

> The end of the guitar is a bit bent.

It's not a bird though it has beautiful voice.

> Who doesn't like to listen to a beautiful guitar being played?

Answer (score 2):

I think answer is

> Pet Dog. [Affenpinscher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affenpinscher) is one of example

It's not a baby though you hold in the arms close to your bosom.

> We can hold pet in the arms

It's not an Indian man though it has long beard.

> Some pet dog has long beard

It's not a monkey though its tail is bent.

> All pet dog has tail is bent

It's not a bird though it has beautiful voice.

> Some pet dog has beautiful voice like Pug Dog.

Comment: last one is not accept dog voice is not beautiful but I like your answer

Comment: @narasimha that is opinion based, for you dog voice may not be beautiful but for others can, and actually I think some dogs have a nice voice!

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Paul's answer, I'll stick with the music theme.

> a saxophone

It's not a baby though you hold in the arms close to your bosom.

> you need to hold it close to play it

It's not an Indian man though it has long beard.

> when you play it, it's like you have a long golden beard

It's not a monkey though its tail is bent.

> the end of a saxophone is usually bent

It's not a bird though it has beautiful voice.

> it's a pretty nice music instrument (but my Trombone is better)